# PyBluez - Changing the value of a specific service

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, pybluez

I am trying to connect my Raspberry Pi with several temperature sensors via bluetooth. The problem is, that I need to change a specific value of the "Trigger"-Service of the sensor, which recognize it at start measuring the temperature. But I am actually not sure how to connect and how to change the value of the service?

The service has a specific uuid. How can I change the value of the service?

This is my code, I am not sure how to go on:

```python
from bluetooth import *

server_sock = BluetoothSocket (RFCOMM)
port = 0
addr = E0:06:E6:B6:AF:21 
server_sock.connect((addr, port))
```

Hope anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Blacktiger800

Comment: Whats the device you are connecting to? Is there a documentation?

Comment: I realized that the device I want to connect to, uses BLE. Therefore I need to know more about BLE. I found the documents of IanHarvey (https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy). Does anybody has experience with this documents?